# Keras Model - Custom Accuracy Function for Three-Level Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to modify the [Keras's code for Siamese Network](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/) to accommodate the three-level label (0, 0.5, 1) and have trouble writing the custom accuracy function.

In the accuracy function below, I get a TypeError saying 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment. I am very new to this field and do not have much experience in dealing with Tensorflow object, so I would really appreciate any advice.

Thank you,

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    pred = y_pred
    pred[y_pred <= 1 / 3] = 0
    pred[y_pred > 1 / 3 and y_pred <= 2 / 3] = 0.5
    pred[y_pred > 2 / 3] = 1
    return K.constant(np.mean(pred == y_true))


# train
rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=rms, metrics=[accuracy])
model.fit([tr_pairs[:, 0], tr_pairs[:, 1]], tr_y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=50,
          validation_data=([te_pairs[:, 0], te_pairs[:, 1]], te_y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign value to a [Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor). In your case you can modify your accuracy function like this:

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    pred = tf.zeros_like(y_pred)
    pred += 0.5*tf.cast(K.all(K.stack([K.less_equal(y_pred, 2/3),K.greater(y_pred, 1/3)], axis=0),axis=0), dtype=tf.float32)
    pred += tf.cast((y_pred > 2 / 3), dtype=tf.float32)
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, pred))
```

Comment: It worked out! Thank you so much for your help. This was really helpful.

Comment: @cub if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that! I didn't know it, and it is great to know!